# Why does '0.00' compare as not equal to 0 in this Python code?

Tags: python, if-statement

What is wrong with my IF ELSE statement?

IF NOT condition, do A.
ELSE, do B.

But the result turns out quite different than I expected. :S

```
data['stock'] = ['0.02', '0.03', '0.04', '0.00', '0.05', '0.04', '0.05']

x = 0
y = len(data['Keywords'])

while x <= y - 1:
    if data['stock'][x] != 0:
        print data["stock"][x]
        a = a + 1
    else:
        print "hello"
        a = a + 1

Output:
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.00
0.05
0.04
0.05
```

Comment: One big problem is your indentation - can you fix it in this post?

Comment: Well, what do you expect?  It seems to be working exactly as I would expect, reading the code.

Comment: The answers below seem to be answering your question, what you should keep in mind is also that since this is the case you will always output the whole list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One obvious problem is that your list contains strings and your code expects numbers. In Python, you are allowed to compare `0` to `"0"` (they compare unequal).

One way to fix it:

```
data['stock'] = [0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.00, 0.05, 0.04, 0.05]
```

Also, that loop looks decidedly un-Pythonic. The first step would be to rephrase it like so:

```
for x in range(len(data['Keywords'])):
    if data['stock'][x] != 0:
        print data["stock"][x]
    else:
        print "hello"
```

If you don't use the value of `x` other than for indexing into the list, then the counter is unnecessary:

```
for val in data["stock"]:
    if val != 0:
        print val
    else:
        print "hello"
```

Note that this assumes that `data["Keywords"]` has the same length and `data["stock"]`. If that's not the case, this code isn't equivalent to yours.

Comment: I agree that the counter is unnecessary. Please bear with me - 3 days old with Python. Will learn as I make more mistakes!

Answer (score 11):

`'0.00'` is a string.  `0` is a number.  These are not equal.